# Java Swing Timers and ActionEvent

Tags: java, swing

I have timer keep running every 1 second.

So right now i have set a variable to show message(msg) every 10sec.

There is button(btn) on msg itself which will show another message(msg2).

So right now is, when i press once, msg2 is showing but the thing is,

the next msg(after 10sec) i don't want the msg2 to be automatically shown without i press btn because right now once i pressed the btn, it will shown for every messages(msg2++).

```
if(ae.getSource() == btn1)
errorMsg.setVisible(true);
```

How do i make it only the msg2 appears once i press button for 2nd msg2 and after?

Thank you

Comment: You need to clarify your question a little. Which variable, what is message. Please format it properly and remove unnecessary new-lines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'm an idiot, just set errorMsg.setVisible to false in parent class